# Getting ajax data from html link

Tags: html, ajax

I bought a template and have asked to the writer but still no respond so far. Actually, I need a quick answer. Any body here can help to fix?

It's about to show  Quick View of a single product detail to show in a window popup when a link is clicked. I have no idea how to put any data and get the data when popup appear, no browser refresh. Please don't ask me what have I done, I have no idea at all. I usually used ajax in a form.

The html link is like this :

```
<div class="quick-view"> 
<a title="Quick view" class="search" href="#"></a>
</div>
```

and the ajax call :

```
$(document).on('click','.quick-view .search,a.quick-view',function(){
    var data = {
    // data here....
    }
    $.post('quick_view.php', data, function(response){
    $.fancybox(response, {
      // fancybox API options
      fitToView: false,
      autoSize: false,
      closeClick: false,
      openEffect: 'none',
      closeEffect: 'none'
    }); // fancybox
    // OWL Product thumb
    $('.product-img-thumb .owl-carousel').owlCarousel(
        {
            dots:false,
            nav:true,
            navText:['<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>','<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>'],
            margin:21,
            responsive : {
              // breakpoint from 0 up
              0 : {
                  items : 2,
              },
              // breakpoint from 480 up
              480 : {
                  items : 2,
              },
              // breakpoint from 768 up
              768 : {
                  items : 2,
              },
              1000 : {
                  items : 3,
              }
          }
        }
    );
    })
    return false;
    })
```

any answers is appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is the question and/or what is not working? Do you reveive any response from quick_view.php and your problem is to display it? Is your problem that your click event does not Trigger your function?

Comment: @Fuzzzzel The script is actually working to show popup. But the default file is quick_view.html. It's only pure html. I need to change to php file so I can get any data. Problem is how to put the data like product id etc in the html link ( should add any id=" "? or class? and how to get the data result in php like GET or REQUEST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add an ID to your elements that fire the event you can access and use it's ID or other Attribute to send it as data in your AJAX-call. To do this you use the event.target which points to the element that triggerred the event. In this way you can use the same call for a whole bunch of elements on the same page:

```
$(document).on('click','.quick-view .search,a.quick-view',function(event){
    // Get the id of the element and add it to the data sent with call
    var data = {
                  elementId: event.target.id
               }
    // Rest of your Ajax call
}
```

Comment: I add something like this and its works gooooood, in html  :  <a title="Quick view" id="datavalue" values="123456" class="search" href="#"></a>  and at ajax :  var pid = document.getElementById('datavalue');
          var data = pid.getAttribute('values');

Comment: That works too. Great. If you'd go by event.target.id you could have several links that work with the same event but send different data. But if the link is unique anyways your way is perfectly alright.

Comment: You were right. I got the problem for more than one link. Popup showing the first <li> data even I click the other link. in the right click - view page source - after looping the list items, many tag has the same id. I am just thinking the way you said. But How?

Comment: this solved the problem ; $('.search').on('click','.quick-view .search,a.quick-view', function(e){var data = $(this).attr('values');var datacat = $(this).attr('datacat');

Comment: Finally it works, great. Though you should consider using a class in this case rather than using an id multiple times. Originally an id is meant to be unique and to identify an element explicitly. However that is more of a semantical matter than a practical one.